# Is it possible to tell Stack to abort a build if it would require unregistering local packages?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

For the last hour I've been waiting for 79 packages to recompile after stack decided to unregister them for one reason or another. It's almost done, so I could consider myself lucky since in the past I had to wait as much as 2-5 hours when such an accident happened. But still, I'd like to avoid similar accidents no matter if they cost 5 hours of my day or "only" 1 hour.

Is there a `stack build --safe` command that would only proceed if there are no irreversible, destructive changes that it would plan to do on my system? E.g. internally it could do a `stack build --dry-run` and would proceed only if that plan doesn't mention "would unregister" items.

Or better yet, could I make the above `--safe` behavior the default per project or even system-wide (e.g. via `.yaml`)? Which I could then perhaps override with `--force` or `--no-safe`.

If no such flags are available, (I've read through `stack build --help` (v1.5.1) and didn't see anything similar) would it make sense to add some such flags to stack?

In the meantime maybe I could work around this by aliasing `stack build` and `stack ghci` in my shell to something like `(stack build --dry run | grep "would unregister" | wc -l | exit-1-if-non-zero) && stack build`. Which might work well, except it would likely take more time to run (+1..10 seconds for each build) than if stack did this internally. And if you have other ideas for workarounds I'm curious to hear them as well.

Comment: May I suggest you check out [Cabal's Nix-style build mode](http://blog.ezyang.com/2016/05/announcing-cabal-new-build-nix-style-local-builds/).

Comment: Of course, cabal's "nix style" builds won't do better than stack here if things do need to rebuild.  In fact, the only case I know where it can do better is when you need to have lots of packages deviate from their snapshot versions, via "extra-deps".  This issue tracks resolving this https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3330 - we know how to solve the problem.  I am hoping to do it before next release, but it is tricky and has gotten deferred a few times before.

This issue also seems relevant -
 https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1875 . Feel free to open issues

Comment: I'm biased, but you're probably better off sticking with stack, "new-build" is still experimental and cabal-install does not really have a good UI track record IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I'm continuing to be inconvenienced by this, but I've found an alleviating workaround.

I've started to store de-duplicated and compressed backups of my `.stack-work` folders like this:

```
$ function foo () {local ourpath="$(readlink -f "$1")"; tar cf - "$1" | zbackup --non-encrypted backup ~/.zbackups/backups/bkp-$(date -u +%FT%TZ | sed 's/:/-/g')-$(echo "$ourpath" | sed 's%/%_%ig') }; foo "./.stack-work"
```

And restore them upon need like this:

```
$ zbackup --non-encrypted restore ~/.zbackups/backups/bkp-2018-03-24T15-19-59Z-_home_wizek_path_to_.stack-work | tar xf - -C .
```

Using https://github.com/zbackup/zbackup

I'm pleasantly surprised by the time and space efficiency of this approach, as for even a single `.stack-work` folder that weighs 1-3GB, the initial `~/.zbackups/` folder only grows to 100-200MB. And all subsequent snapshots only seem to increase this by 0-10-50MB, depending on the amount of new unique data, I presume.

Disclaimer: This is not yet perfect because this still depends on some kind of foresight or manual diligence on my part: e.g. doing backups before builds where I think unregistering might occur, and/or doing backups after successful builds that changed the dependencies. Doing both is not an issue though at all, because deduplication ensures 0MB space usage increase. At least in some cases it can combat some cursing that used to happen when I started to see "unregistering, unregistering, unregistering".